# how to send email from localhost with php CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, localhost

I am working on a php codeigniter project and I want to sent emails from my localhost.

Following is my controller functions.

```
        $config = Array(
              'protocol' => 'smtp',
              'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.google.com',
              'smtp_port' => 465,
              'smtp_user' => 'sender@gmail.com',
              'smtp_pass' => 'password'
    );

    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from("sender@gmail.com");
    $this->email->to("receiver@gmail.com");
    $this->email->subject("Email with Codeigniter");
    $this->email->message("This is email has been sent with Codeigniter");

    if($this->email->send())
    {
        echo "Your email was sent.!";
    } else {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

Note that I have enables the 'extension=php_openssl.dll' extension in php.ini. My php.ini file is located in C:/AppServ/php5. When I run the code, my page loads with errors.

These are the errors:

> The following SMTP error was encountered: 1923818231 Unable to find
>   the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you
>   configured PHP? Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN Failed to send AUTH
>   LOGIN command. Error:  Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 705

Comment: Did you activate the `php_openssl` extension in PHP? Activate it by editing `php.ini` and removing the `#` comment

Comment: I have enabled the 'extension=php_openssl.dll' extension in php.ini. My php.ini file is located in C:/AppServ/php5 and C:/AppServ/php7 folders

Comment: What about the one in `wherever\apache\bin` that is the one that is likely to be used by the web server

Comment: This may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TO7MfDcM-Ho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHPMailer. Its available here [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). You can use it like this:

```
public function send_mail()
    {
        require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP(); // we are going to use SMTP
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // enabled SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  // prefix for secure protocol to connect to the server
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // setting GMail as our SMTP server
        $mail->Port       = 465;                   // SMTP port to connect to GMail
        $mail->Username   = "mail@gmail.com";  // user email address
        $mail->Password   = "password";            // password in GMail
        $mail->SetFrom('mail@gmail.com', 'Mail');  //Who is sending 
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject    = "Mail Subject";
        $mail->Body      = '
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Title</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h3>Heading</h3>
            <p>Message Body</p><br>
            <p>With Regards</p>
            <p>Your Name</p>
            </body>
            </html>
        ';
        $destino = receiver@gmail.com; // Who is addressed the email to
        $mail->AddAddress($destino, "Receiver");
        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Remember to set access for less trusted apps in your gmail account

Comment: But to answer the question.... make sure you have activated the `php_openssl` extension in the php.ini file used by Apache/PHP

Answer (score 3):

In your `$config` array, try this instead:

```
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Codeigniter Library to send email from localhost and live server as follows:

```
$localhosts = array(
    '::1',
    '127.0.0.1',
    'localhost'
);

$protocol = 'mail';
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $localhosts)) {
    $protocol = 'smtp';
}

$config = array(
    'protocol' => $protocol,
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'Your-Email',
    'smtp_pass' => 'Your-Email-Password',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'starttls'  => true,
    'newline'   => "\r\n",
);

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from("From-Email");
$this->email->to("To-Email");
$this->email->subject("New user contacts");
$this->email->message($final_mail);
$flag = $this->email->send();

if($flag){
    echo "Email sent";
}else{
    echo "Email sending failed";
}
```

For more details refer to this [article](https://www.coderanks.com/article/sending-html-email-using-codeigniter-from-localhost-and-live-server) of Coderanks.com.