# Unable to send email using SMTP gmail config in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, codeigniter-3

Below are my code and I refer all examples in stack overflow and codeigniter user guide. still I unable to solve this

```
public function send()
{
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_user'] = '**********@gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '********';
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = 30;
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from('uvizag@gmail.com', 'admin');
    $this->email->to('siddharthaesunuri@gmail.com, siddhu.php@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Registration Verification:');
    $message = "Thanks for signing up! Your account has been created...!";
    $this->email->message($message);
    if ( ! $this->email->send()) {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    } 

}
```

[image]

[image]

How Can I solve this error ? could please favor to me

Comment: This error normally refers to a connection issue with the remote SMTP server, depending on firewalls or misspelled domains.

Comment: And check your email account with this link https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: I checked what you mention @QuỳnhNguyễn still facing same error. How can I solve this any examples ?

Comment: What's your hosting service?

Comment: GoDaddy Linux server

Comment: Can you try source code in my answer.

Comment: So, what worked? What is the full solution? In other words: how does your _final_ `send()` function look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you try this?

```
$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
'mailtype'  => 'html', 
'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.

$result = $this->email->send();
```

And make sure you had setting your email account with
[Allowing less secure apps to access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Comment: Showld the host not be `smtp.gmail.com`: `'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'`?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir Each SMTP Email Host will have different SMTP endpoint. What's Email service you using?

Comment: I am using Gmail's email service. Click [HERE](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636577521614258862-2909356251&hl=en&rd=1)

Comment: @RazvanZamfir Did you allow Less secure apps access to your Account? https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: Just now. My application is made on Codeigniter 3. It is not that insecure. What does _less secure_ mean?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir Because when you use your Gmail account for SMTP Gmail Server. Your Codeigniter need to access to your Gmail account for sending an email. And your Codeigniter is one of less secure apps (Google told that).

Comment: @RazvanZamfir About ssl end point is: `smtp.gmail.com` is okay.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: I have allowed less secure apps access to access my Gmail and no change has happen.

Answer (score 5):

Quỳnh Nguyễn's answer worked for me too. However I think it's worth pointing out that my code fails unless I put the line

```
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

Without that line, gmail complaints about wrong user/password :|

Regards

Comment: Thanks, this was problem

Answer (score -1):

I had difficulties making this native CI feature to work. I had to implement an external library: PHPMailer. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128015/how-to-send-email-from-localhost-with-php-codeigniter).

Comment: Please do not just post link.